# cannot invoke 'runaction' with an argument of type 'skaction' when trying to play sound

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a game in swift and want to play different sounds when the user makes some moves. When the sound should be played is determined in GameViewController, but I can't play the sound from there. So I tried to use this technique to call a GameScene function from GameViewController:

in GameViewController:

```
GameScene.wordsFoundSound()
```

in GameScene:

```
//globaly (outside: class GameScene: SKScene {...})
let foundSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Chomp.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

//inside class GameScene: SKScene {...}
class func wordsFoundSound() {
        runAction(foundSound)
    }
```

But I get this error: cannot invoke 'runaction' with an argument of type 'skaction'

I can't figure it out...please help me and thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I got so concentrated on my first idea that I forgot to search for other solutions...I didn't know you can pay sounds with AVFoundation. Sorry for the question

I got the answer from here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/78264/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-5